# My boyfriend is Turkish citizen but has a green card. Does he need a visa to visit me in Spain?

Tags: visas, spain, turkey, turkish-citizens

My boyfriend is Turkish citizen but has a green card. Does he need a visa to visit me in Spain?

I read in a website that is not necessary, but in other places yes I'm confused, can someone help me please?

Comment: What do you mean by "green card"---he is a US permanent resident?

Comment: If you wanted to say "green passport" then he does not need a visa for < 90days stay

Comment: @arved what's a green passport ?

Comment: @Calchas that's the common name given to that card, if that's indeed the case the OP's boyfriend is a permanent resident of the US

Comment: @blackbird57 I agree, but it, in my view, needs context when the question doesn't otherwise touch on the USA.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_passport It is the second one called "Special Passport"

Answer (score 6):

Short answer is **yes**

According to [this](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Portal/es/ServiciosAlCiudadano/InformacionParaExtranjeros/Documents/listapaisesvisado.pdf) list from the Spanish Foreign Affairs department (which should probably be your only reference), Turkey is on the list of countries that need a Schengen visa to visit Spain. The criteria for this is very often citizenship, rather than status in a third country.

Furthermore, their [list](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/NUEVAYORK/en/ServiciosConsulares/Documents/Visa%20Schengen%20%28english%29.pdf) of requirements state you must have a Green Card to apply in the US, which indicates permanent residents are not exempt from a travel visa.

Comment: The green card is one of several documents that can be used to show eligibility to apply for a Schengen visa in the US; almost any nonimmigrant visa other than a B or C visa will do as well.  Basically the applicant has to show legal residence in the US; some resident aliens don't even have any visa (for example, Canadians don't need them).